# How to recover from Node.js request pipe with ECONNRESET error?

Tags: node.js

My site is all in `HTTPS`. When I show some pictures from other non-HTTPS sites, I rewrite the request from my server and pipe the response to the client as follows.

```
request.get(imageUrl)
    .on('response', function(response) {})
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
}).pipe(res);
```

Sometimes it throws the error of 
`{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }`.

So how can I recover from the error to make my site continue to serve?

Comment: Is this error happening in .get(imageUrl) or someplace else?

Comment: It is the .get(imageUrl) when my network is not well